# What if the lagrange gives out an answer which is the critical point of the constraint function

Tags: calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Example :

min $f(x,y)=x^4-y^4$ subject to $(x-5)^3-y^4≥0$

When we use the lagrangian theorem we end up with the point $(5,0)$ which is a critical point of the constraint. 
A necessary condition to use the lagrangian theorem was to make sure that the point we end up with is not a critical point.

I couldn't really get it. How did we end up with $(5,0)$ then? Would this mean that $(5,0)$ is not a minimiser for the function on the constraint, because the point we ended up with the lagrangian is the critical point of the constraint function?

Also another question How will I minimise $f$ on this constraint then?

Comment: How did you end up with $(5,0)$? That doesn't seem to be a critical point of the Lagrangian. Your specific problem has a simpler solution. What you are asking is equivalent to minimizing $g(x) = x^4 - (x-5)^3$ over $x \ge 5$. (Try to minimize over $y$ first to get this.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The theorem says that any extremum of $f$ subject to $g = 0$ where the gradient of $g$ is not $0$ is a critical point of $f + \lambda g$.
$(5,0)$ turns out to be the minimum of $f(x,y) = x^4-y^4$ subject to $g(x,y) = (x-5)^3 - y^4 = 0$, but it is not a critical point of $f(x,y) + \lambda g(x,y)$: in fact 
$$ \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} (f + \lambda g)(5,0) = 500$$
This is possible because the gradient of $g$ is $0$ there.

So this is illustrating that besides the critical points of $f + \lambda g$ you have to consider points where $g=0$ and $\nabla g = 0$ as candidates for extrema.